# dplyr check values between first and last permanent change

Tags: r, any, dplyr

I have data structured like this

```
set.seed(2)
require(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame("TIME" = c(sample(seq(1:20), 20, replace = F), seq(21:30)), 
                   "ID" = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10)), 
                   "LOC" = c(sample(c("X", "Y"), 20, replace = T), c("X", rep("Y", 9))))
```

and I'm trying to use dplyr to create a variable to indicate whether or not a given ID has a change in time that is permanent (PERMANENT =1) or not (PERMANENT=0). I can't use `first()` or `last()` because that ignores the in between values. If for instance they go from X to Y and back to X again like in the case of A and B, the indicator should be 0 for every instance of A and B in the data. However C starts at X and stays at Y in all other instances.

I tried to use indexing in a mutate function, but something isn't working.

```
data %>% 
  arrange(ID, TIME) %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(LOC = as.character(LOC),
         PERMANENT = ifelse(last(LOC) != "X" & any(LOC[2:length(ID) -1]) != "X"), 1, 0)
```

Like I said the output should indicate C moved permanently, while A and B bounced around in the data set.

the expected output is what happens if you run the following code:

```
data$PERMANENT<-ifelse(data$ID%in%c("A","B"),0,1)
```

Comment: Can u show the expected output.  Do you need `data %>% arrange(ID, TIME) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(PERMANENT = as.integer(n_distinct(data.table::rleid(LOC == "X"))<=2)) %>% as.data.frame`

Comment: How do you tell if the change is permanent or not?  ie A stays on X for the last 4 observed time periods.  Is that not considered permanent?

Comment: There's a typo, parenthesis after `-1]` should be after `0)` like this: `& any(LOC[2:length(ID)-1] != "X"),1,0))`

Comment: Aurele's answer resolved the syntax on the ifelse statement, but the output should show that only C is a permanent transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a go at it with `dpylr`.  I am assuming an ID is permanent if it hasn't changed since it's second observed time period.

```
  set.seed(2)
  data<-data.frame("TIME" = c(sample(seq(1:20),20,replace = F),seq(21:30)),"ID" =c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",10)),"LOC" = c(sample(c("X","Y"),20,replace = T),c("X",rep("Y",9))) )


     data %>% arrange(ID, TIME) %>%
       group_by(ID) %>% 
       mutate(timeObs = row_number(), SecondLoc = LOC[timeObs == 2], Change = LOC != SecondLoc) %>% 
       filter(timeObs > 1) %>% 
       summarize(Permanent = sum(Change) == 0 ) %>% 
       right_join(data, by = 'ID')
```